# Tool to create an image library

Tags: web-apps, images

I'm looking for a way to create an image library for work. The goal is that our members can use this library to help explain things to their customers.

We're looking for a platform/CMS that's basically ready out of the box. But I do have some programming experience, so a bit of tinkering on my side wouldn't be a problem. Even a wordpress plugin would be ok if it meets the requirements.

**There are a couple of things that we really need:**

First of all, this will be a tool used by our members and they should be able to log in to access the library.

They have to be able to search for the right image. There should be 3 ways to do this:

- Navigate a folder structure
- Search by name/description
- Use tags

**Software/platforms I've looked at:**

I've been looking for a while now and have found some platforms/software to use but I haven't been able to find something that checks all the boxes.

I've looked at Bynder but they don't have the option to set up a folder structure.

Pimcore DAM looked great but is quite complicated/overwhelming to get up and running. They told me it should be possible to create what I'm looking for but I really don't know where to start.

After looking at a couple of other questions here, I found Plone and Piwigo. They look promising but I'm still researching them to find out if they match our requirements...

Finally I had to check out one.com their new galleries but they're still in beta so it's pretty limited in terms of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Joomla (CMS) with JCE (Joomla Content Editor extension). Notice that Joomla may be confusing if you're not get used to it. JCE doesn't have an option for image tags and descriptions as far as I know (I don't know the paid version) however you can search by filename in file manager section. You can edit user types and access rights for uploading.

[Joomla homepage](https://www.joomla.org)

[JCE Demo](https://demo.joomlacontenteditor.net)

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

If you plan to use this or need help you can ask here.