# Self-hosted image database

Tags: cms, photography, self-hosted, information-management, gallery

I am looking for a decent self-hosted photo management database where users can upload, download and organize and share the images in a common corporate database.

These are the requirements:

- self-hostable preferably with a cheap web hoster (PHP, WordPress or something) but a dedicated Linux server would also suffice
- be able to read and index EXIF, XMP data to for searching, including date, artist, resolution, geolocation
- tag images with arbitrary searchable tags
- organize images in albums (same images can appear in multiple albums)
- add searchable description to images and albums
- multi user support: restrict access to certain albums or images by users similar to nextCloud/ownCloud/DropBox
- share link to certain images or albums with the public
- bulk upload and download of images
- nice to have: bulk edit of images (tags, EXIF, XMP, add to album)
- less than 1000 € single purchase or 20 €/month (hosting costs not included) for up to 100000 JPEGs and 50 users

Comment: the best option should be jce. please see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48558/tool-to-create-an-image-library/49392#49392 user levels can be defined as well.

Comment: @onurcano22 That seems oriented at managing content for display in a website, not for photo management. It lacks... *most* of the features above.

Comment: you can handle the other features with Joomla and its extensions